# Visual Studio Code unresolved import `sys`, `time`, `errno`

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Python 3.7.2, Windows 10, VSCode 1.37.1,

Seems like it would be a very common problem people would have but a quick internet search gave no relevant results. I know about the `.env` file and I can set that up correctly, but for some reason there are certain standard packages that VSCode can't find. 3 of them are `sys`, `time`, and `errno`. Steps to reproduce:

```
import sys
import time
import errno
```

VSCode is fine with most of the other standard packages as far as I know, just not the above 3. Anyone else having the same problem?

*EDIT*
Sorry I meant 1.37.1, not 1.27.1 as was originally posted. I've corrected it now in the original question above, I hope it's not confusing.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code 1.27.1 is very old, and so you're probably using an outdated version of the Python extension. Make sure you're using the latest version of both VS Code and the Python extension as there have been bugs in the Microsoft language server for those modules in the past.

But at least with the Microsoft language server 0.3.59.0 (beta), I am not having issues:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I meant 1.37.1, the most recent version. I have the same problem on 2 separate Windows 10 machines and a MacOS Mojave machine (last time I checked was 1.37.0 though, I'll check again).

Comment: Then assume it will be fixed in the next version of the Microsoft language server or try using the beta.